# Django JSONField - get source text

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

When using a JSONField, the contents are automatically decoded from JSON into python objects when reading the value.  I have a use-case where I'm encoding the string back into JSON to embed in a template.  Is there any way to just get the raw JSON string from the object?

Comment: You can use `json.dumps` to convert Python objects to a JSON blob.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - I'm aware.  That's not what I'm asking. Instead of `json.dumps(json.loads(json_string))` I want to just get `json_string`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Django uses `psycopg2.extras.Json` under the hood. You will need to cast the field as text to get the original out as plain text [1]. Use django's `Cast` function [2] to annotate your queryset:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import TextField

models_with_json_text = Model.objects.annotate(
    json_as_text=Cast("json_field_name", TextField())
)
```

[1] http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#json-adaptation

[2] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#cast

Comment: I was hoping for something like `json_field_name__text` but was expecting that I'd have to write my own `models.Field`.  This is a pleasant surprise!  Thank you!